# How is this JavaScript structure called?

Tags: javascript

```
(function(global, $data, undefined) {
   $data.Entity.extend('TodoDBModel.TodoItem', {
     'Id': { key:true,type:'Edm.Guid',nullable:false,required:true },
     'InSync': { type:'Edm.Boolean',nullable:false,required:true }
  });
})(window, $data);
```

Is this simple function or any type of class?

How we define these parameters `global, $data, undefined` and last line of code that ends with function close parentheses and `(window, $data)` parameters?

Comment: This is an interesting question, however - I think a more informative name would really help it. "What is this structure called" is hard to find in a google or stack overflow search. To make it more applicable to the general public, I suggest you change the name - up to you. (maybe "what's a function( that immediately calls itself called"? Or even something more codey. I'm not sure)

Comment: Fair point @benjamin-gruenbaum, the vagueness of the title was what drew me to edit it - but how do you know from reading that the function calls itself immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) - immediately invoked function expression.

Citing wikipedia:

> An immediately-invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced "iffy") is a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope using JavaScript's function scoping. Immediately-invoked function expressions can be used to avoid variable hoisting from within blocks, protect against polluting the global environment and simultaneously allow public access to methods while retaining privacy for variables defined within the function. This pattern has been referred to as a self-executing anonymous function, but Ben Alman introduced the term IIFE as a more semantically accurate term for the pattern.

What's happening here is you're defining a function (through a function expression) and immediately invoking it. This provides encapsulation.

For example if someone was to override the value of the language primitive value type `undefined`* it'll get it as the third parameter. It also provides access to two parameters (data, which is a variable in the code and `window` (the global object in the browser) as `global`.

<sub>* seriously, has anyone ever actually overwritten undefined? Also, it's impossible in modern browsers</sub>

Here is a more basic example:

```
(function(i){ // declare a function that accepts a single parameter - i
    alert(i);//alert the value of i
    // Next, we'll invoke the function we just declared with the value 5,
    // which means i will be 5 in the function
})(5);
```

Comment: thanks for you explanation i really stuck on it now i'm cleared